# Is $\lim_{x→a} f(x) $ equivalent to $\lim_{h→0} f(a+h)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x→a} f(x) = \lim_{h→0} f(a+h)$ does this always hold true? Intuitively these two things seem to describe same concept, and I've seen some algebraic manipulations that implicitly use this identity. Are there any scenarios where this falls apart? Also, if it does hold true, why is that (putting the intuition aside)? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $f (a+h) $.

Comment: Whoops, yes. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: The limits are certainly not equivalent since they're numbers, not relations.

Comment: They both are part of equivalent derivative definitions, too.

Comment: Sure, but the title is about ‘equivalent limits’. My comment was only about the phrasing (same problem with the way many questions use ‘solving’ indiscriminately).

Comment: @Bernard What do you think would've been the correct way to phrase the question?

Comment: @MadRabbit: ‘the limits are equal’, or ‘$\ell=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is equivalent to $\ell=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$’, or ‘both limits  exists equivalently’, for instance, depending on what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are equivalent because for every $x$ there is an $h$ (which equals $x-a$), and conversely, for every $h$ there is an $x$ ($=a+h$). It is essentially a renaming of the variables.

The answer would be different for a non bijective change of variable.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\text{sgn}(x)$$ does not exist, while

$$\lim_{t\to0}\text{sgn}(t^2)=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, then by $\epsilon$-argument, somehow it is like $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, for $0<|h|<\delta$, then $|(a+h)-a|=|h|$, so $0<|(a+h)-a|<\delta$, set $x=a+h$, then $|f(a+h)-L|=|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, this shows $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(a+h)=L$. Another way is similar.